# How to I format my log message

Tags: java, logging

I would like to format my log message before being printed out on the console [Logger.fine](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#fine%28java.lang.String%29)

e.g. How do I format "{0} has {1} apples with him", so the inputs are John and 10

I would prefer a logging framework which provides a solution to this and I don't want to format these messages separately. JDK6 specific logging classes don't seem to have these granularity.

Comment: If you use [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org), you can write: `log.debug("{} has {} apples with him", "John", 10);` SLF4J has a binding that redirects back to `java.util.logging`.

Comment: Please rephrase the question.  Tokeninzation is about breaking up a string into constituent pieces and generates outputs not inputs.  Your example suggests you are asking how to format, not tokenize.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [MessageFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

```
String s = MessageFormat.format("{0} has {1} apples with him", "John", 10);
```

or [String.format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
String s = String.format("%1$s has %2$d apples with him", "John", 10);
```

Comment: For simple cases like this you can just leave out the `1$` and `2$` and use `"%s has %d apples with him"` for `String.format()`.

Comment: +1 for MessageFormat - i was able to convert all my log statements to use MessageFormat will very little effort

Comment: For me this immediately led to this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809633/what-is-the-difference-between-messageformat-format-and-string-format-in-jdk-1-5

Comment: This is not necessary, see answer by David Groomes below.

Answer (score 5):

Even with just JDK logging, you can use a custom [`Formatter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html) to handle formatting of log messages with parameters.

For (a simplistic) example:

```
public class MyFormatter extends Formatter {

    /**
     * @see java.util.logging.Formatter#format(java.util.logging.LogRecord)
     */
    @Override
    public String format(final LogRecord record) {
        return MessageFormat.format(record.getMessage(), record.getParameters());
    }
}
```

Then to use it, you can configure a `logging.properties` file with:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = com.example.MyFormatter
```

Comment: This is not necessary, see answer by David Groomes below.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `String.format`:

```
String.format
   ("%s has %s apples with him", "John", "10");
```

Comment: String.format will have performance penalty when used directly for logging

Answer (score 2):

JUL (`java.util.logging`) supports curly-brace style parameters out-of-the-box. You do not need a third-party logging framework. See below for a single-class working example (spoiler, I still recommend using SLF4J instead of JUL).

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class JavaUtilLoggingExample {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JavaUtilLoggingExample.class.getName());

    /**
     * A java.util.logging (JUL) example adapted from the JavaDoc for java.text.MessageFormat.
     * See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/MessageFormat.html
     *
     * Written for the StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7036765
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int planet = 7;
        String event = "a disturbance in the Force";

        log.log(Level.INFO, "At {1,time} on {1,date}, there was {2} on planet {0,number,integer}.", new Object[]{planet, new Date(), event});

        // The following is printed (pretty good!):
        //
        //        Jan 02, 2022 8:06:59 PM JavaUtilLoggingExample main
        //        INFO: At 8:06:59 PM on Jan 2, 2022, there was a disturbance in the Force on planet 7

        // However, try to modernize your code and use java.time.LocalDateTime instead of java.util.Date and you will be
        // met with a surprise. Given this log statement:
        log.log(Level.INFO, "At {1,time} on {1,date}, there was {2} on planet {0,number,integer}.", new Object[]{planet, LocalDateTime.now(), event});

        // The following is printed (not good!):
        //
        //        Jan 02, 2022 8:06:59 PM JavaUtilLoggingExample main
        //        INFO: At {1,time} on {1,date}, there was {2} on planet {0,number,integer}.

        // Why? See this discussion. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66870717

        // By contrast, a similar (but less feature-ful) version of the above log statement written using the
        // SLF4J 'org.slf4j.Logger' class is below. It is much more succinct but it doesn't offer as many formatting
        // features.
        //
        // log.info("At {}, there was {} on planet {}.", new Date(), event, planet);

        // In conclusion, I continually wind back up with SLF4J in even my trivial Java programs despite my
        // once-yearly well-intentioned "Hey, why don't I reduce external dependencies as much as feasible. Can I just use JUL?"
        // efforts. The SLF4J API fits well in practice.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it here for myself:

```
import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

...

//configuring
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("App");
logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);

ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler(logger.getName()+"-log.%u.%g.txt", 104857600, 3, true);

Formatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter() {
    private String format = "[%1$tF %1$tT.%1$tL] [%2$-7s] %3$s %n";

    @Override
    public synchronized String format(LogRecord lr) {
        return String.format(format, new Date(lr.getMillis()), lr.getLevel().getLocalizedName(),
                lr.getMessage());
    }
};

consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter);
fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter);

logger.addHandler(consoleHandler);
logger.addHandler(fileHandler);

// using
logger.info("test");
logger.warning("test");
logger.severe("test");
```