# Java MessageFormat and LocalDate

Tags: java

I'm using

```
MessageFormat.format("Hello {0}", "World"));
```

Now I want to use `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` as parameters but as far as I can see `MessageFormat.format` doesn't support `java.time`!

So I have to use

```
MessageFormat.format("Today is {0,date}", 
              Date.from(LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
```

This is terrible!

Is there a better way to use `MessageFormat` with `java.time`? Or are there better solutions to replace placeholders in a text that considers Locale configuration?

**Update**

I'm aware of how to format LocalDate and LocalDateTime but I have the requirement to format a message with various types.

Example

```
MessageFormat.format("Today is {0,date} {1,number} {2}", aDate, aNumber, aString);
```

Where is the replacement for `MessageFormat` with `java.time` Types?

Comment: LocalDate supports format itself using a DateTimeFormatter (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a bug report about supporting `java.time` in `MessageFormat`.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8254654

Until this is solved I will go with the suggested workaround and convert `LocalDate` etc. to `java.util.Date`

Answer (score 11):

There had been an [issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8016743) opened for this, which was resolved as "won't fix". The reason is that:

> The `MessageFormat` is designed to work with `java.text.Format` classes, so it uses `DateFormat`/`SimpleDateFormat` to format date/time. Providing support for `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` to format `java.time` types (`TemporalAccessors`) may complicate the `MessageFormat` API. It is always recommended to use `java.util.Formatter` which provides support for formatting `java.time` types.

So you should use [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) instead:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US);
int someNumber = 10;
String someString = "Hello";
formatter.format("Today is %tD and someNumber is %d %s", LocalDate.now(), someNumber, someString);
System.out.println(sb);
// prints "Today is 03/30/21 and someNumber is 10 Hello"
```

This works with any kind of `TemporalAccessor`.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I am not the person who suggested `DateTimeFormatter`. That's Mr R in the comments. I edited the answer to show how you can format a number in the message as well. Did the ISO 8601 format made you think it's `DateTimeFormatter`? I changed it to another format.

Comment: The problem is that %tD does not consider the region. I get 03/30/21 instead of 30.03.2021

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Ah, you want the whole format to be locale sensitive. `Formatter` only supports locale sensitive month name, day of the week, and am/pm. But from the bug report, it seems like `MessageFormat` is just _not_ going to support `java.time` :(

Comment: Now you understand my question :-)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I mean, the comment in the bug report seems to say that `Formatter` is a sort of newer version of `MessageFormat` that works with `java.time`, so I doubt you can find another similar API in the standard library that does similar things but only with the minor difference that it supports localised date formats. I would suggest looking in Apache Commons... but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @Abra I think OP wants the format to change, according to the locale of the `Formatter`.

Comment: @Abra As Sweeper said I want to have it formatted like the region settings

Answer (score 4):

MessageFormat allows to create and set up a custom format for any argument.

```
val randomDate = LocalDate.EPOCH.plusDays(random.nextInt(20_000));
val fmt = new MessageFormat("Today is {0}");
fmt.setFormat(0, new SummaryDateFormat());
val out = fmt.format(new Object[]{randomDate});
System.out.println(out);
```

Here is a sample implementation of your custom format:

```
 public class SummaryDateFormat extends Format {
    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(final Object obj, final StringBuffer toAppendTo, final FieldPosition pos) {
        toAppendTo.append(String.format("%tA, %<tB %<te", obj));
        return toAppendTo;
    }

    @Override
    public Object parseObject(final String source, final ParsePosition pos) {
        return null;
    }
}
```